# Clear screen in a Linux terminal using assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, x86, nasm

Is there a way to clear the screen in a terminal window with nasm?

By clear the screen, I mean emulate the `Ctrl-L` hotkey. Remove all text from the window.

Comment: First, you should say what OS in which you want to clear the screen. Second, you should be looking at that OS's native API for functions that do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash:

```
echo -ne "\033[H\033[2J"
```

In C:

```
printf("\033[H\033[2J");
```

How do I find the string:

```
$ strace -e trace=write clear >/dev/null 
write(1, "\33[H\33[2J", 7)              = 7
Process 7983 detached
```

Comment: As in, what does that string of numbers and characters do?

Comment: Looks like a VT100 escape sequence to me. `/033` is octal for the ASCII "Escape" character and `[` is the second character needed to start an escape sequence. `H` is "move cursor to home". `J` is "Erase all characters from current position to end of screen".

Comment: Actually, the `2` at the start of `2J` modifies it and makes the second escape sequence "Erase the entire screen". From this I'd assume the `\033[H` is entirely optional.

Comment: @Brendan - If you omit the \033[H, the screen clears but the cursor is left where it was. Source: Just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this NASM program:

http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/snake.asm.txt

There's an interesting part showing how to write escape sequences to the stdout:

```
%define SC_write        4   ; eax = write(ebx, ecx, edx)
%define ESC         033q

; (...)

refresh:
        mov eax, ESC | ('[' << 8) | (BOTTOMROW << 16)
        stosd
        mov eax, ';0H' | (SI << 24)
        stosd
        mov edx, edi
        mov edi, outbuf
        mov ecx, edi
        sub edx, ecx
        xor ebx, ebx
        lea eax, [byte ebx + SC_write]
        inc ebx
        int 0x80
```

The code doesn't probably do exactly what you want to, but it'd be easy to modify it to output `\033[H\033[2J`. Also have a look here:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Plus, if you want your code to be portable, think of using some library that's compatible among different terminals, like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

(**EDIT**: That was for Linux. If you're on Windows, I'd try [this](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/59673/59673/clear-screen/).)

Comment: I think you want `push eax`, or just `push`-immediate, then `mov ecx, esp`.  Your `refresh:` uses EDI as a pointer before initializing it.  `mov edi, outbuf` comes later in your function, after `stosd`.