# Clean console on assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, system, nasm

Is there anything similar to `system("cls");` that exists on C for Assembly?

I'm using NASM to compile and I'm working on a x86 linux.

UPDATE 1: Here's my modified code to integrate sugestion:

```
section .data

%define SC_write        4   ; eax = write(ebx, ecx, edx)
%define ESC         033q


MAX_PALAVRA equ 40

(...)

num1        dd  0
num2        dd  0
result      dd  0
tamstr      dd  0

section .bss
strnum      resb    MAX_PALAVRA
opc     resb    2

section .text

global _start

   refresh:
        mov eax, ESC | ('[' << 8) | (BOTTOMROW << 16)
        stosd
        mov eax, ';0H' | (SI << 24)
        stosd
        mov edx, edi
        mov edi, outbuf
        mov ecx, edi
        sub edx, ecx
        xor ebx, ebx
        lea eax, [byte ebx + SC_write]
        inc ebx
        int 0x80

_start:

mov eax, ds
mov es, eax
```

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206629/linux-nasm-assembly-clear-screen-in-terminal

Comment: I've tried the code that's on that link but when compiling it gives me "error: shift operator may only be applied to scalar values" and "error: '|' operator may only be applied to scalar values"

Comment: Post your code or screenshot to see what you are doing.

Comment: `system("cls")` is a horrible construct to start with, but that is just launching an external program. Of course you can launch external programs from asm too.

Comment: You could always go way old school and output a bunch of newlines to console.

Comment: I suggest ignoring the incomplete (and pretty bad) NASM code in the answer you copied from, and only look at the other answer to the same question. If should tell you all you need to implement a solution in NASM: `write(1, "\33[H\33[2J", 7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To imitate the terminals `clear` command have in a `.data` section:

```
ClearTerm: db   27,"[H",27,"[2J"    ; <ESC> [H <ESC> [2J
CLEARLEN   equ  $-ClearTerm         ; Length of term clear string
```

then whenever you want to clear the terminal do:

```
mov eax, 4                          ; Specify sys_write call
mov ebx, 1                          ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Stdout
mov ecx, ClearTerm                  ; Pass offset of terminal control string
mov edx, CLEARLEN                   ; Pass the length of terminal control string
int 80h
```